# Scoped storage is working in API level<30

Tags: android, android-studio, storage, scoped-storage

I have tested Scoped storage in api level lower than 30 (`min API 23 in my app`).It is working fine in every android version.(both read and write media(photo/video)

**My question is:**
Should I use Scoped storage for api level less than 30 or I should use the old method to handle that?

**Save Image code :**

```
private boolean saveImageToExternalStorage(String imgName, Bitmap bmp){

        Uri ImageCollection = null;
        ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){

            ImageCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY);

        }else {

            ImageCollection = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        }

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imgName + ".jpg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE,"image/jpeg");
        Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(ImageCollection, contentValues);

        try {

            OutputStream outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
            bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,outputStream);
            Objects.requireNonNull(outputStream);
            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception e){

            Toast.makeText(this,"Image not saved: \n" + e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        return false;


    }
```

**Read image code :**

```
    private ActivityResultLauncher<String> mTakePhoto;

        mTakePhoto = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
                result -> binding.imageView.setImageURI(result)
        );
mTakePhoto.launch("image/*");
```

Comment: If files api makes things easier, use that. If scoped storage makes things easier, use that. However, Files would be comparatively faster than the `DocumentFile`s.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean with 'using scoped storage'.

Comment: @DarShan scoped storage is mandatory for API30+. It is introduced in 2021. My question  is I have tested it in api 23,24,25,26,27,28,29 it is working. My doubt: it is mentioned for api30+ but is working in 23 also. So whether I should use that in lower version

Comment: @blackapps [link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage)

Comment: I know that link and it stays unclear what you did with it. How you used it. Scoped storage is no feature but a restriction.

Comment: @blackapps  check I have updated code. I can confirm that it is working fine starting from API 23  to API 33(android 33). But I'm testing is in emulator. My problem is , I don't whether it will work in every device or not. If it will not work in lower api other devices(real smartphone) that is a big problem

Comment: There is nothing in the code you posted that has anything to do with scoped storage.

Comment: `saveImageToExternalStorage()` Confusing function name. You could better name it saveImageToMediaStore() as that is what you do. Further the data column RELATIVE_PATH is only usable for Q+. Below Q you should use DATA column.